# LISTAGG in SQL is returning a row with null values

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, listagg

I have 2 tables A and B, B is having a foreign key relationship with A i.e.,(b.detail_id = a.id)
I want to apply LISTAGG query on one of the column in B.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT b.delivery_cadence, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.delivery_cadence) 
delivery_cadence, a.id FROM A a, B b WHERE b.detail_id = a.id AND a.id = 1236565;
```

The above query is returning me a row with all values as null, But I want no rows. How can I achieve this?
If it's not possible any alternative solution for this.

a.id = 1236565  is not exists in A table.

Comment: `a.detail_id = a.id` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad `b.detail_id = a.id` and edited

Comment: use explicit join instead of implicit join, which mean use `join ... on` and stop using `,`  to join tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `having count(b.delivery_cadence) > 0` eg

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT b.delivery_cadence, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.delivery_cadence) 
delivery_cadence, a.id FROM A a, B b WHERE b.detail_id = a.id AND a.id = 1236565
HAVING COUNT(b.delivery_cadence) > 0
```

Comment: There should be `count(b.delivery_cadence) > 0` to exclude ID's with **all** nulls

Answer (score 1):

Say you have tables like these:

```
create table a(id) as
(
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual
);
create table b(detail_id, delivery_cadence) as
(
    select 1, 'x' from dual union all
    select 1, 'A' from dual union all
    select 2, 'y' from dual
);
```

If I understand well, you need (in ANSI join syntax):

```
SQL> SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT b.delivery_cadence, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.delivery_cadence) delivery_cadence,
  2          a.id
  3  FROM A
  4      inner join B ON b.detail_id = a.id
  5  where a.id = 1236565
  6  group by a.id;

no rows selected
```

For a value of `ID` that exists in tables, you get:

```
SQL> SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT b.delivery_cadence, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.delivery_cadence) delivery_cadence,
  2          a.id
  3  FROM A
  4      inner join B ON b.detail_id = a.id
  5  where a.id = 1
  6  group by a.id;

DELIVERY_CADENCE         ID
---------------- ----------
A,x                       1

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Kudos for proper `JOIN` syntax.